# Ebook Formatting for all platforms

Tags: formatting, ebook

My kindle ebook does not display properly on my pc and mac browsers. It appears fine on the kindle app for my android phone.

Is it possibe to format an ebook so that it can show up in the same way on all platforms (e.g. mac and pc browsers, kindle, iphone, android etc.)?

Would this be a one step or a multiple step process?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: multiple-step and time-consuming/expensive

Google [eBook formatting](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=ebook%20formatting) and see the hundreds of different methods for doing this. It ranges from long, in-depth methods that would require you to strip your book down to plain text and add semantic information, to supposed 'converters' that will do it all for you.

There are 'professionals' who will, for a price, convert your book manually to the different formats, and give it love and attention.

Frankly speaking, I've never read a single eBook that was one-hundred-percent formatted right - there will always be some odd glitch or quirk. Some eBooks range from bare-bones formatting that barely looks better than a `.txt` file, through to fancily done ones that are obviously professional (*Hunger Games* comes to mind as a really well-done eBook).

Speaking from a programming side, there are so many different devices out there - smartphones, Kindles, iPads/tablets etc, and so many different book formats that getting something to look 100% right on 100% of devices isn't going to be possible.

You will need to research what's right for you - are you going to individually create five or six different forms of your book, or would you rather pay and have it done? Personally, (again, speaking from my programmer side), *never* trust *any* automatic convertor to do things right.

Edit: Also, see [this post](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/3395/best-e-book-formatting-process?rq=1) on eBook formatting, it has some useful links and answers.